# Ajax request fails due to wrong url

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, url

I'm experiencing a strange problem using Ajax. I have a page called Main.html, available at the local url 'http://localhost/Main.html', which is styled using Bootstrap.

When the page loads, jQuery checks if a particular file exists, and then loads a specific html inside a Bootstrap panel; it may be an html for registering/logging into the service, or directly the home page; the home page is loaded from the file Home.html, available at 'http://localhost/Home.html'.

This home page has some elements in it, and the main one is a search bar with some further options; what happens is that, when the user inserts something in the bar, selects the appropriate options and clicks on "Search" button, a jQuery function called search(), which is in a script in the page Home.html, makes an Ajax request to the page 'Home.php' with the data inserted above.

The ajax request is:

```
function search()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Home.php',
        data: {query: $('#query').val(), searchtype: $('#searchtype').val(), second: $('#second').val()} ,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
            $('#mainPanel').empty();
            $('#mainPanel').append(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
}
```

What I would expect is to load the answer directly in the panel; the problem is that the Ajax request DOESN'T call the right url, and so fails; what happens is that it doesn't call 'http://localhost/Home.php?query=Something&searchtype=some&second=blabla', but it calls 'http://localhost/Main.html?query=Something&searchtype=some&second=blabla': it applies the request to the url of the open page and not the one I want.

I'm used to Ajax calls, I often called php files using Ajax, and this is the first time this happens to me.

---

Some further informations:

1) I tried to change the url in the request to 'http://localhost/Home.php' and '/Home.php', but nothing changed.

2) The file 'Home.php' contains some lines to connect to a MySQL database (which succeeds), then this lines:

```
$query=$_POST['query'];
$type=$_POST['searchtype'];
$second=$_POST['second'];
```

And then some operations on this variables; after a large number of switches, there will always be an 'echo' call.

3) I'm using Chrome and its inspector: nothing is shown in the console output, but from the 'Network' tab I understood that the call to 'Home.php' fails: the output of the query is

> Notice: Undefined index: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\Home.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: searchtype in C:\xampp\htdocs\Home.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: second in C:\xampp\htdocs\Home.php on line 13

so, it seems that the variables are not passed during the request.
Furthermore, here are the headers of the request:

> General
>
> Request URL:http://localhost/Home.php
>
> Request Headers
>
> Provisional headers are shown
>
> Accept:*/*
>
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>
> charset=UTF-8
>
> Origin:http://localhost
>
> Referer:http://localhost/Main.html
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
>
> Form Data
>
> query:Dani second:Name

So it seems that the parameter 'searchtype' is not accepted... but this is quite strange, considering that it appears in the url.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file which is changing requests going to .php files to .html ones?

Comment: Do you use header function at home.php file?

Comment: Is the file called Home.php OR home.php?

Comment: Actually I added this line to httpd.conf in order to process php tags in html files:
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

Comment: The file is called Home.php; I don't use any header.
The beginning of the file is:
'<?php
$hostname="127.0.0.1"; 
$username="root";  
$password="";       
$database="SocialNetwork";  
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password, $database);
if($con->connect_errno)
{
 echo "connection to database failed";
}
$query=$_POST["query"];
$type=$_POST["searchtype"];
$second=$_POST["second"];
$array=explode(" ", $query);
$sql="";'

Comment: Your OS and name of any framework used

Comment: Windows 7 64bit, Browser: Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m, CORS enabled, AdBlock Plus enabled, Avira Browser Security enabled. No other things, I write the code with Notepad++, and I use XAMPP to execute it

Comment: How are you calling the `search()` method on button click or from some other function. If button click then comment the whole button element pls

Comment: <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="search()">Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5393m27j/
This is running fine test this on your local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88809/discussion-between-cybersupernova-and-tenik).

Comment: I understood something, in the meanwhile: I was using the wrong method to get two of the values; searchtype and second are <select>, so now I use $('#searchtype  option:selected').text(), but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long discussion in CHAT we figured it out.

You have to attach a listener on your button instead of using html onclick
`<button id="search"></button>`
and prevent the default event of form submission by
`$('#search').on('click', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); search();});`
This line must be written below your `search()` method declaration